# Jquery pageload select change not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, select

I have a weird issue.
I'm trying to change a selected option on page load. This works on desktop but not on mobile.

```
<select id="gui-form-details-type" name="customer[type]">
  <option value="private" selected="selected">Option1</option>
  <option value="company">Option2</option>
</select>
```

What I tried is things like:

```
$(function(){

 $('body').live('change','#gui-form-details-type', function() {
   $("#gui-form-details-type").find('option[value=private]').removeAttr("selected");
   $("#gui-form-details-type").find('option[value=company]').attr('selected','selected');
 }).change();

 // and
 $("#gui-form-details-type").on('change', function(){
   .....
 }).change();

 // and        
 $(document).on('change', '#gui-form-details-type', function(){
  ....
 }).change()

});
```

I even wrapped it in a function that was fired on page load. Is there any particular reason why this doesn't work on iOS or Android?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because you are triggering a change event on the body.  The body will not match the child element selector, in the first snippet.  In the second snippet, if the element doesn't exist yet, it would not be able to find it to bind on it.  Which is assumingly why you had a delegate in the first snippet.  The third snippet is the same as the first issue.

Comment: @Taplar: Ok so how would I fix this? Why would it not match? I don't get it anymore :)

Comment: `$(parent).on(event, childSelector, eventHandler)` says when the parent ecounters one of those events, to see if it originated from a nested child that matches the child selector.  If it does, apply the eventhandler to the child with that event.  If you trigger the event on the parent, the event originated on the parent, not a child.  And a delegate event binding will never match on the parent.

Comment: @Taplar: Ok seems fair enough! Probably starring at this for too long now, do you mind to make a quick example?

Answer (score 1):

This would be my proposed fix.

```
function alterGuiFormDetailsType() {
  const $element = $('#gui-form-details-type');

  if ($element.length) {
    $element.find('option[value="private"]').removeAttr('selected');
    $element.find('option[value="company"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
}

$(document.body).on('change', '#gui-form-details-type', alterGuiFormDetailsType);

alterGuiFormDetailsType();
```

Extract the logic out of the event handler and call it directly on page load.  If the element does not exist yet, it will try to execute, but won't do anything.

Comment: Thx for your example. I've tested the code and it seems to work on Android but not on iOS. Any idea what can cause that behaviour?